# Printing text through print server on asp.net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to print a text content, I use this code for this, but don't work, the paper is empty

```
      PrintDocument myPrintServer = new PrintDocument();

        myPrintServer.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = @"\\servername\printerName";
        StringReader myReader = new StringReader("test string content");
        myReader.Close();
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add code to render your string to the graphics context of the PrintDocument object you create.  See the [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage.aspx) and note how they use the event handler to render text to the page:

```
          pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler
             (this.pd_PrintPage);
          pd.Print();
```

and then:

```
// The PrintPage event is raised for each page to be printed.
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) 
{
```

...

```
      ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, 
         leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
```

...

```
}
```

If you want to send pre-formatted data directly to the printer from C#, you can use the [RawPrinterHelper defined in this MSDN example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) and do things like
    string s = "Hello"; // device-dependent string, need a FormFeed?

```
// Allow the user to select a printer.
PrintDialog pd  = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
if( DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this) )
{
    // Send a printer-specific to the printer.
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, s);
}
```

Comment: thk you, but there is an another way to send string to printer without drawing? let printer(zebra zpl) interpreted this string.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include sending a raw string to the printer.  Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you sending the myReader data to the print server?  I don't see that in your code snippet.

You might want to check out the [example on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(VS.71).aspx)  Specifically the part where it shows the PrintPageEventHandler being using to actually draw on the print canvas.